# xjc and java 11: How to enable episode plugin?

Tags: java, jaxb, java-11, xjc, java-module

I'm using the **command-line xjc** from the `jaxb-ri 2.3.3` maven artifact
(https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-ri/2.3.3/jaxb-ri-2.3.3.zip).

It seems that the episode plugin cannot be loaded (more precisely it isn't found at all by the `ServiceLoader` which is used behind the scenes within xjc's plugin architecture):

```
unrecognized parameter -episode
```

Tested on openjdk-11.0.2 on both linux and windows.

What needs to be done to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is yet to be back ported to 2.3 release. Looks like [3.x](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/releases/tag/3.0.0-RI) was just out, though I can't find the binary distribution.

So I tried with latest 3.0.0-M5 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-ri/3.0.0-M5/jaxb-ri-3.0.0-M5.zip and it worked fine for me.

Usage now shows the extensions as well.

[image]

Comment: Why do think it is not backported? It is part of the bundle, all the classes are there (and btw, this is not a 3.0 feature - it exists for a very long time). The plugin mechanism does simply not find the plugin(s) - and I like to know why and potentially how to mitigate this (possibly using a stable/final version).

Comment: I was referring to xjc usage with java 11. Checkout [issue](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues/1474) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that issue, describing more or less the same thing as this question. Do you have knowledge about any workarounds here (beside using java 8/jaxb 2.2)?